# Video playback with multiple audio tracks to separate audio devices

Tags: audio, video, sync, vlc-media-player

I have an mkv file with multiple audio tracks (separate languages) that should be played simultaneously from the same device. That is the video should be played with track #1 on my mac, while audio track #2 should also be played in sync from the external audio card. I have tried VLC, separating into 2 different videos, but the option to play another media synchronously, doesn't support multiple audio outputs.

The solution posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/751184/how-to-sync-two-looping-videos-with-mplayer-and-upd/792635?newreg=2265f5854c0446249b8d64a35210035f) for mplayer, was the same as VLC and the only other [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/556182/how-to-play-multiple-audio-track-of-video-simultaneously-on-vlc) was basicly opening separate instances of VLC and playing them at the same time.

Is there another approach to this?

Comment: any chance to get a solution to this? I know it's been a while but I was looking to do the same, basically, two people watch a video and each gets to choose its own preferred language as long as the audio is available.

Comment: [How to play a movie listening to two sound tracks simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/q/1064686/297473)