# Play multiple audio tracks of a video simultaneously on MPC-HC

Tags: audio, media-player-classic

I have an MP4 file containing two audio tracks, and would like MPC-HC to play them both simultaneously.

[I saw that this is possible on VLC](https://superuser.com/questions/556182/how-to-play-multiple-audio-track-of-video-simultaneously-on-vlc), and would like to know whether there is a way to achieve this on [MPC-HC](https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc), as well.

When Googling I came across [this old thread on the doom9 forums](https://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-164878.html), but that did not seem to work for me (or I'm not doing it correctly).